# How to give MySQL users CREATE DB rights?

Tags: mysql

I want to give MySQL users the ability to create new databases, and have ALL privileges on these, but not on the other database. I've tried to create a STORED PROCEDURE for this, but it's not working out. This is my procedure (**NOTE:** UPDATED CODE BELOW):

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE DEFINER = 'root'@'localhost' PROCEDURE createdb(IN newdb VARCHAR(255))
BEGIN
  CREATE DATABASE newdb;
  SET @newdbuser = USER();
  GRANT ALL ON newdb.* TO '@newdbuser';
  FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
END //
DELIMITER ;
```

I call the procedure using:

```
CALL createdb('newtestdb');
```

But what happens is that the database 'newdb' (variable name) is created. Trying to access that database as the mortal user who called the procedure doesn't work either: access denied.

**Question:** What is wrong with my PROCEDURE? Or am I attacking the problem from the wrong angle?

***UPDATE***
Based on longneck's answer, I've revised the procedure to:

```
DELIMITER //

CREATE DEFINER = 'root'@'localhost' PROCEDURE createdb(IN newdb VARCHAR(255))
BEGIN

PREPARE stmt1 FROM "CREATE DATABASE ?";
PREPARE stmt2 FROM "GRANT ALL ON newdb.* TO '?'";

EXECUTE stmt1 USING @newdb;

SET @newdbuser = USER();
EXECUTE stmt2 USING @newdbuser;

FLUSH PRIVILEGES;

END //

DELIMITER ;
```

However, when calling this procedure using "CALL createdb('testing');" I get:

```
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '?' at line 1
```

What am I missing?

Comment: You can't use objects in placeholders.  Build the string with the object name, not a ?.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand you entirely. Do you mean that database names need to be pre-defined?

Comment: see my updated answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this isn't a rights problem. mysql doesn't support variables as object names (where objects are tables, databases, columns, etc.). you will have to use prepared statements and build your command as a string. see http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?98,152150,152161#msg-152161

for example, your PREPARE statements need to look like:

```
PREPARE stmt1 FROM concat("CREATE DATABASE ", @dbname);
PREPARE stmt2 FROM concat("GRANT ALL ON newdb.* TO ", @username);
```

not that this is NOT injection safe. make sure your have sanitized your "parameters" (database name, user name) before using these statements.

also, you're granting your privilege wrong. `TO '@newdbuser'` assigns the privilege to users connecting from a computer called `newdbuser`. you need to put the `@` sign after the username.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, but I can't figure it out entirely. I've updated my question (I couldn't do code formatting in comment).

Answer (score 1):

There is no such privilege as CREATE DATABASE. Only the CREATE privilege grants the creation of database, tables, and indexes

- Under MySQL 5.5

  - [CREATE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/privileges-provided.html#priv_create) (<-- This is what you want)
  - [CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/privileges-provided.html#priv_create-temporary-tables)
  - [CREATE VIEW](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/privileges-provided.html#priv_create-view)
  - [CREATE ROUTINE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/privileges-provided.html#priv_create-routine)
  - [CREATE TABLESPACE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/privileges-provided.html#priv_create-tablespace)
  - [CREATE USER](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/privileges-provided.html#priv_create-user)
- Under MySQL 5.1

  - [CREATE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/privileges-provided.html#priv_create) (<-- This is what you want)
  - [CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/privileges-provided.html#priv_create-temporary-tables)
  - [CREATE VIEW](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/privileges-provided.html#priv_create-view)
  - [CREATE ROUTINE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/privileges-provided.html#priv_create-routine)
  - [CREATE USER](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/privileges-provided.html#priv_create-user)
- Under MySQL 5.0

  - [CREATE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/privileges-provided.html#priv_create) (<-- This is what you want)
  - [CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/privileges-provided.html#priv_create-temporary-tables)
  - [CREATE VIEW](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/privileges-provided.html#priv_create-view)
  - [CREATE ROUTINE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/privileges-provided.html#priv_create-routine)
  - [CREATE USER](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/privileges-provided.html#priv_create-user)